# How do I enable the Android 6 System UI Tuner?

Tags: settings, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-options

I read [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-system-ui-tuner) that there are some hidden settings in addition to the Developer Options on Android 6. These are also mentioned in various reviews and referred to on this site also. Apparently they can be accessed after doing certain gestures to make the cog in the quick settings menu spin.

Unfortunately it does not spin for me (and others), even if not disabling animations in developer settings as has been suggested.

Does anybody know any other secrets about how to enable that menu?

Comment: How long did you hold it? Have you tried it multiple times? What's your device model?

Comment: It worked for me a couple of days ago, this way, which I read somewhere and quoting from memory , it sure sounds funny *pull down notification bar with two fingers and slide on the cog with one finger and then tap and hold it*. It didn't work first time but when i held the cog in a way i could see it (partially), for about 30 seconds, it spun and i finally got the UI. IMO, nothing much in it for all hoops to reach there

Comment: What do you mean by "slide on the cog"? Thank you.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I have tried several times, and tried holding it 30 seconds once. Phone model is Ulefone Power. Thanks.

Comment: @nsandersen Holding the Gear Icon (Settings shortcut) for like 3-4 seconds worked for me, though the double finger swipe didn't work for me.

Comment: Using one finger to slide down on the cog wheel followed by holding it as described

Comment: @beeshyams - OK, so select it (giving a light grey circle highlight), slide the finger down again (so the circle goes?) and hold for a while? Or does the highlight circle need to be there at all times? Thank you.

Comment: It worked on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, I just needed to open the quick setting panel, then press and hold the Setting (cog) icon until it started spinning in about just 1 second, then released the finger and it would prompt about System UI Tuner. However, I don't know if it works on other device, especially with customized/vendor UI.

Comment: The highlight circle needs to be there all the while. Sliding with one finger is before this step

Comment: OK, if it should be easy and not require finger contortions, then it is probably safe to assume it has been disabled for this 6.0 ROM, even if it appears to be fairly plain stock. Thank you.